# mongodb, lookup by hash key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid6

I have a collection like this:

- Category:

```
{_id: Object:Id(...), code: 'drink', name: 'Soft Drink and Beer'}
{_id: Object:Id(...), code: 'fast-food', name: 'Burger and Chicken Fry'}
```

- GroupPeople:

```
{_id: Object:Id(G1), categories: {'drink' => 5, 'fast-food' => 3}}
{_id: Object:Id(G2), categories: {'drink' => 2}}
```

The wishing output I really want:

```
{_id: Object:Id(G1), categories: {'Soft Drink and Beer' => 5, 'Burger and Chicken Fry' => 3}}
{_id: Object:Id(G2), categories: {'Soft Drink and Beer' => 2}}
```

I try in many ways, but there is no luck. Do you have experience with this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation with MongoDB **3.6** and above

```
db.GroupPeople.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "categories": { "$objectToArray": "$categories" }}},
  { "$unwind": "$categories" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Category",
    "let": { "category": "$categories.k" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$$category", "$code"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "category"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$category" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "categories": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$category.name",
        "v": "$categories.v"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "categories": {
      "$arrayToObject": "$categories"
    }
  }}
])
```

And with **3.4.4** and above

```
db.GroupPeople.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "categories": { "$objectToArray": "$categories" }}},
  { "$unwind": "$categories" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Category",
    "localField": "categories.k",
    "foreignField": "code",
    "as": "category"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$category" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "categories": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$category.name",
        "v": "$categories.v"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "categories": {
      "$arrayToObject": "$categories"
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZwxDdzL3TrF)

Comment: Cool, but I am using version mongo 3.4 , I could not use "pipeline" in the query.  Is it any way to work around of it

Comment: That's awesome! You should keep both 2 versions for your answer. That will help lots of people looking for this case

Comment: That's great! @Ashh, Worked for me.
Thanks